# Diskspace status bar missing after ubuntu 13.04 update

Tags: upgrade

After updating Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 the disk space remaining on the bottom of the Nautilus status bar is now missing.
The updated filemanager Files, does not seem to have any settings that I can display this with.
How do I get it to display the current diskspace remaining on the current drive, at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot, because makers of Nautilus (now called "Files") removed it along with many other usefull features. I miss this feature too. Only thing lef to do is to look for another file manager.

Comment: Wow, that's a bit harsh.  That's the one thing you expect a file-manager to do - tell you how much disk space you have left... Has anyone got any suggestions except for Dolphin, that is a good replacement?

Comment: You can try Marlin. I tried it long time ago when it was in deep beta stage. It hade good features, but it crashed often so i stopped useing it. Might be ok now. Here i found [link](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/09/install-marlin-file-browser-in-ubuntu.html).

Comment: Just found Nemo file browser. It has status bar. Check it out [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-install-nemo-file-manager-in.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just search in the the dash "disk usage analyzer" with out the quotes and open it up, it will show you how much space is used and how much is left for all of the storage devices plugged into the computer including the hard drive(s).  I also hate how they removed that feature from the file browser,but this is a way around that without 3rd party software.

Answer (score 0):

files/location options/properties tells you free space