# How to see the amount of free disk space in files browser with 13.04 (Raring Ringtail)

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, files, configuration, disk

Up to the previous Ubuntu versions you could easily switch on a status line at the bottom of the files browser, which showed useful infos like the amount of free disk space, number of files in directory, number of selected files and amount of data of selected files.

How do I get these informations with Raring Ringtail?

*sigh*

Imagine you want to copy a 5 GB file to a USB drive or memory stick and the computer just says "not enough free space" - how should you know whether you have to delete just a few MB to make it fit or wheter the device is full? And when you multi-select files to copy or delete, do you then have to calculate by yourself?

Soemtimes I really wonder how others are using their computer when a feature is removed that seems to be totally essential. Maybe they have tons of terabytes of hard disk drives and a couple of 64+ GB flash memory sticks so they never run out of free space.

Comment: Here is the bug report related to this problem:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=684943

Comment: It's not from within Nautilus, but "System Monitor"'s "File Systems" tab was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to switch file browsers or submit a bug to have the feature re-added. The maintainers of that project decided to remove it for some (IMO) nonsense reason that I will likely never be convinced of.

Ranting aside your only options are to find a fork where someone put it back, like [nemo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294421/how-do-i-install-nemo-file-manager), use a different file manager (there are several), or complain a lot in bug reports and mailing lists till the maintainers put it back or allow you to put it back (it is opensource after all).

Comment: Going to rant more in a comment, just fair warning. I am not sure why it was removed but it seems to be "cause OS X finder doesn't have it". Or, "cause people are to stupid to know what free space is". Honestly, I don't know why someone would go out of their way to remove such a feature. But they did. Complain, find another manager, and move on, and know your not alone in thinking it was an utterly stupid move. [See here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1173872)

Comment: oops, i did not find that bug report. filed another one.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1187039

Answer (score 2):

A tad late, perhaps, but right-clicking in the directory and choosing the "Properties" option at least shows you the amount of free space on the device concerned. Although it is not, in my opinion, a desirable solution, it beats the disk usage analyzer option.

Answer (score 1):

This question [Diskspace status bar missing after ubuntu 13.04 update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287510/diskspace-status-bar-missing-after-ubuntu-13-04-update) talks about a way to solve the problem
"Just search in the the dash "disk usage analyzer" with out the quotes and open it up, it will show you how much space is used and how much is left for all of the storage devices plugged into the computer including the hard drive(s)."

I am however running KDE so I am unable to test if this solution works or not.  Please let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Sadly that is not a good answer (not your's their's)

Comment: Well yes it works, but it is not suitable. Not at all.

Comment: Yeah, that tool is either too top-line (combines all partitions - so you might have actually run out on one partition!) or too detailed such that it takes half an hour to give results.